# How to draw triangular grid in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, grids

Is there an easy way to draw a triangular grid in TikZ, like this?

[image]

Comment: Just a pointer. Sorry for not offering real code. I'd draw it just like there were no `grid`. Use `foreach` to draw the three sets of lines.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Like Leo said: use `\foreach` and some math:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*\rows{10}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \row in {0, 1, ...,\rows} {
        \draw ($\row*(0.5, {0.5*sqrt(3)})$) -- ($(\rows,0)+\row*(-0.5, {0.5*sqrt(3)})$);
        \draw ($\row*(1, 0)$) -- ($(\rows/2,{\rows/2*sqrt(3)})+\row*(0.5,{-0.5*sqrt(3)})$);
        \draw ($\row*(1, 0)$) -- ($(0,0)+\row*(0.5,{0.5*sqrt(3)})$);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, for an equilateral triangle, those should all be `sqrt(3)`, not `sqrt(2)`. (Though maybe you didn't want an equilateral one, in which case, ignore me.)

Comment: Well, that is rather embarrassing. Don't tell anyone! ;)

Answer (score 39):

A *funny* solution (have you ever used [`lindenmayersystems`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=643) library?):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{triangular grid}{\rule{F->F-F+++F--F}}
  \path[draw=black,
  l-system={triangular grid,step=1cm,
    angle=-60,axiom=F--F--F,order=4,
  }]
  lindenmayer system -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty clever!

Comment: Great example of lateral thinking -- congratulations!

Comment: The question is not "have you ever used `lindenmayersystems` library", but "did you even know about it's existence". Very nice!

Comment: @TomBombadil How to use TikZ without reading the manual? How to read pgfmanual without reading all chapters? ;-)

Answer (score 16):

A slightly different solution using a matrix transformation and clipping:

```
\newcommand*{\rows}{10}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xcoord}{cos(60)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ycoord}{sin(60)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgftransformcm{1}{0}{\xcoord}{\ycoord}{\pgfpointorigin} 

    \path[clip,preaction = {draw=black}] (\rows,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,\rows) -- cycle;
    \draw (0,0) grid (\rows,\rows);
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,\rows} {
        \draw (0,\x) -- (\x,0);
    } 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Very beautiful!

Comment: Nice. (nitpick: the last `(\rows,0)` can be `cycle` :P)

Comment: Very nice (and very convenient when one needs to draw something on triangular grid).

Answer (score 6):

You could abuse the `pgfplots` tenary plot feature for this.  On the plus side it allows you to easily plot data in that grid.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{ternaryaxis}[
    xticklabels={},
    yticklabels={},
    zticklabels={},
    major tick length=0,
    minor tick length=0,
    minor tick num=2,
    every axis grid/.style={},
    grid=both,
    ]
  \end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

Next code defines command `\grid` which draws a triangular grid made with triangular nodes. `\grid`'s parameter is the number of rows. `minimum size` in `tri/.style` is the diameter of triangle's circumscribed circle.

With nodes instead of just lines, it's easier to use the grid as base for nice `TiKZ` drawings.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand{\grid}[1]{
\foreach \i [count=\row from 0, remember=\row as \lastrow (initially 0)] in {0,...,#1}{
    \foreach \j [count=\column from 0, remember=\column as \lastcolumn (initially 0)] in {0,...,\i}{
        \ifnum\row=0
            \node[tri](0-0){0-0};
        \else
            \ifnum\column=0
                \node[tri, anchor=north](\row-0) at (\lastrow-0.corner 2) {\row-0};
            \else
                \node[tri, anchor=north](\row-\column) at (\lastrow-\lastcolumn.corner 3) {\row-\column};
            \fi
        \fi}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tri/.style={draw=gray, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, 
                            minimum size=2cm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}]

\grid{5}

\begin{scope}[draw=yellow!30!black, very thick, fill=yellow!80!black]
\filldraw[fill opacity=.7] (5-2.corner 2)--(4-0.corner 1)--(4-1.corner 1)--
         (2-1.corner 1)--(3-2.corner 3)--(4-4.corner 1)--(5-4.corner 2)--cycle;

\draw (4-1.corner 1) -- (4-3.corner 1) (4-2.corner 1)--(2-1.corner 1);
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps one should call it \trid instead of \grid ;)

Comment: piggybacking on Ignasi's excellent code: https://pastebin.com/i1fyUCQH

Answer (score 4):

A MetaPost version, as a complement. It is based on a recursion inspired by Paul Gaborit's use of the `lindenmayersystems` library. I borrowed much code from [my answer to a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119602/how-to-create-a-sierpinski-triangle-in-latex/228123#228123).

Note that at each recursion only the midpoints triangle is drawn, in order not to draw the same segments more than once (which would result in a much thicker rendering of these segments).The main, biggest triangle being drawn only once, before the recursion takes place.

To be run with LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef triangular_grid(expr A, B, C, n) = % Recursive macro à la MetaPost
   if n>0:
      save midAC, midBC, midAB; pair midAC, midBC, midAB;
      midAC = .5[A, C]; midBC = .5[B, C]; midAB = .5[A, B];
      triangular_grid(A, midAB, midAC, n-1);
      triangular_grid(midAB, B, midBC, n-1);
      triangular_grid(midBC, midAC, midAB, n-1);
      triangular_grid(midAC, midBC, C, n-1);
      draw midAB--midAC--midBC--cycle;
   fi;
enddef;
beginfig(1);
   u := 14cm; pair A, B, C; A = origin; B =  (u, 0); C = u*dir 60;
   draw A--B--C--cycle; 
   triangular_grid(A, B, C, 4);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

At risk of starting a "code golf" war, but in the spirit of "TIMTOWTDI",

```
\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=sqrt(.75),xslant=.5]
\def\n{12}
\clip[preaction=draw](0,0)--(\n,0)--(0,\n)--cycle;
\draw(0,0)grid(\n,\n)[xslant=-1](0,0)grid(\n,\n);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want to avoid double-drawn grid lines, then line 4 is

```
\draw(0,0)grid(\n,\n)[xslant=-1](0,0)grid[ystep=\n](\n,\n);
```

Notes:

- No point including a picture here, as it looks like those above.
- Yes, this is similar to answer contributed by @finite

Comment: I am guesing the meaning of `TIMTOWTDI` Is it in VNese?

`

Answer (score 2):

I am eager to join the code party. The question is natural - a kind of should-be-asked one. Below are simple solutions with plain TikZ and Asymptote, based on the same simple idea: the `for` loop; without using tricks, `sin`, `slant`, etc.

[image]

**TikZ code** (use `scale=1.5` for scaling as desired)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={n=8;}]
\foreach \i[parse=true] in {0,...,(n-1)}
\foreach \j[parse=true] in {0,...,(n-\i-1)}
\draw[shift={(60:\i)},shift={(\j,0)}] (0,0)--(0:1)--(60:1)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Combining `[shift={($(60:\i)+(\j,0)$)}]` is possible with `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`.

**Asymptote code** (run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/)

```
size(6cm);
int n=8;
path p=(0,0)--(1,0)--dir(60)--cycle;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
for (int j=0; j<n-i; ++j)
draw(shift(i*dir(60)+(j,0))*p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most elegant, but slightly simplified (from my perspective) variant of Caramdir's answer.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*\gridsize{10}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,thin]

        \foreach \a in {1,...,\gridsize}{
            \draw[dotted] (0, 0) -- (\a, 0) -- ({cos(60)*\a}, {sin(60)*\a}) -- cycle;
            \draw[dashed] ({\gridsize-\a}, 0) -- (\gridsize, 0) -- ({\gridsize-cos(60)*(\a)}, {sin(60)*(\a)}) -- cycle;
            \draw[red] ({cos(60)*(\gridsize-\a)}, {sin(60)*(\gridsize-\a)}) -- ({(\gridsize/2)+cos(60)*\a}, {sin(60)*(\gridsize-\a)}) -- ({cos(60)*\gridsize}, {sin(60)*\gridsize}) -- cycle;
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\caption{Triangular grid}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Charles Staats contributed to this solution in [Drawing scaled triangles with their bottom left corner at the same coordinates in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158769/drawing-scaled-triangles-with-their-bottom-left-corner-at-the-same-coordinates-i) as I became fixated on using polygons.

Answer (score 1):

This is a full-page triangular grid I created recently. My approach was to slant vertical lines in both directions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin={0.4in,0.8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nopageno}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\cols}{60}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rows}{55}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\slant}{cot(60)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\height}{0.5 * \rows * tan(60)}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.38,rotate=90]
    \clip       (0, 0) rectangle (\cols, \height);
    \draw[gray] (0, 0) rectangle (\cols, \height);

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\from}{-2 *\cols}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\to}{2 * \cols}
    \foreach\i in {\from, ..., \to} {
        \draw[gray, dotted, xslant=\slant]  (\i, 0) -- (\i, \height);
        \draw[gray, dotted, xslant=-\slant] (\i, 0) -- (\i, \height);
    }

    \foreach\j in {0, ..., \rows} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{0.5 * \j * tan(60)}
        \draw[gray, dotted] (0, \y) -- (\cols, \y);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Full-page triangular grid]