# How to draw grids of geometric shapes with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw an image like the following:

[image]

I did this using the following Tikz code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   [hexagon/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,
    draw, minimum size=1cm, anchor=center}]

\foreach \x in {0,...,2}
  \node at (\x, 5) [hexagon]{};
\foreach \x in {0,...,3}
  \node at (\x-0.5, 4.12) [hexagon]{};
\foreach \x in {0,...,4}
  \node at (\x-1, 3.25) [hexagon]{};
\foreach \x in {0,...,3}
  \node at (\x-.5, 2.38) [hexagon]{};
\foreach \x in {0,...,2}
  \node at (\x, 1.52) [hexagon]{};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a better way to code this, using fewer manually-calculated approximations in Tikz? Also, as can be seen, the lines overlap in a weird inexact way. Can I avoid that too?

Comment: This is very similar to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6019/drawing-hexagons/6025#6025) question, the answers to which you can modify to your liking

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I realized that this question is slightly different form the drawing hexagons of yore...so, how about this solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [hexagon/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,
    draw, minimum size=1cm, anchor=center}]
  \foreach[evaluate=\y] \y in {-2,...,2}
  {
  \pgfmathparse{5-abs{ \y }}
\foreach \x in {1,...,\pgfmathresult}
\node at (abs \y /2 +\x, sqrt 3 * \y/2) [hexagon]{};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields: [image]