# Shifted hexagons in TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Recently there was a [great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107444/19287) in [How to draw a 3D hexagonal structure with TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107409/how-to-draw-a-3d-hexagonal-structure-with-tikz)

But I noticed a small "bug" which I can't seem to be able to fix. I stripped the code down that shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[%
      every node/.style={anchor=west,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,draw,inner sep=0.5cm},
      transform shape]
    \node (A) {A};
    \node (B) at (A.corner 1) {B};
    \node (C) at (B.corner 5) {C};
    \node (D) at (A.corner 5) {D};
    \node (E) at (D.corner 5) {E};
    \foreach \hex in {A,...,E}
    {
      \foreach \corn in {1,...,6}
        \draw[fill=white] (\hex.corner \corn) circle (2pt); 
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code draws five nodes with hexagonal shape, but the hexagons are a few, but always a different "number of few", pixels "off", as shown in this picture:

[image]

- Which value is responsible for this?
- Why is the "shifting" happening with different strength?
- How to fix it?

Comment: +1 for: "I stripped the code down that shows the problem:"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You would need `outer sep=0` and also `inner sep` is dependent on the node contents and the node size change accordingly. Instead you can use `minimum height/width` keys.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[%
every node/.style={anchor=west,
regular polygon, 
regular polygon sides=6,
draw,
minimum width=2cm,
outer sep=0,
},
      transform shape]
    \node (A) {A};
    \node (B) at (A.corner 1) {B};
    \node (C) at (B.corner 5) {C};
    \node (D) at (A.corner 5) {DECF};
    \node (E) at (D.corner 5) {E};
    \foreach \hex in {A,...,E}
    {
      \foreach \corn in {1,...,6}
        \draw[fill=white] (\hex.corner \corn) circle (2pt); 
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, this works as expected. Thank you very much. :) I already noticed that the letters increase the shifting, but also with empty nodes the problem was there. But this is now also fixed thanks to `outer sep`. :)