# Space saving and loops in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins

There are two main problems with the source/output pair of mine below (which is meant to be used for Hex games listings) :

1) In my printout at least, there's an unnecessary left margin and a top margin (I don't know where they come from) so the right and bottom part get eaten out.

2) My ugly 11-line code snippet whose intended meaning is a loop on a-b-c-...-k can surely can be replaced by a one-line smart loop ?

Any ideas on how to fix those issues ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}

\addtolength{\textwidth}{4cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{4cm}

\addtolength{\hoffset}{-2cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-2cm} 


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (-1,0) coordinate (Z);
\path (Z)++(0.2,0) coordinate (Y);
\foreach \bx in {0,5.5,11,16.5}
{
\foreach \by in {0,-6,-12,-18,-24}
{
\path (Y) ++(\bx,\by)  coordinate (X);

\draw (X)  ++(0.2,0.2) node[anchor=south east] {$a$};
\draw (X)  ++(0.6,0.2) node[anchor=south east] {$b$};
\draw (X)  ++(1.0,0.2) node[anchor=south east] {$c$};
\draw (X)  ++(1.4,0.2) node[anchor=south east] {$d$};
\draw (X)  ++(1.8,0.2) node[anchor=south east] {$e$};
\draw (X)  ++(2.2,0.2) node[anchor=south east] {$f$};
\draw (X)  ++(2.6,0.2) node[anchor=south east] {$g$};
\draw (X)  ++(3.0,0.2) node[anchor=south east] {$h$};
\draw (X)  ++(3.4,0.2) node[anchor=south east] {$i$};
\draw (X)  ++(3.8,0.2) node[anchor=south east] {$j$};
\draw (X)  ++(4.2,0.2) node[anchor=south east] {$k$};
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,11}
{
\draw (X)++(\x*0.2,-\x*0.4) ++(-0.2,0.4) node[anchor=east] {$\x$};
\foreach \y in {0,0.2,...,2}
{
\draw (X) ++(-0.4,0) ++(\x*0.4,0) ++(\y,-\y*2)  -- ++(0,0.2) -- ++(0.2,0.2) -- ++(0.2,-0.2)  -- ++(0,-0.2) -- ++(-0.2,-0.2) --cycle;
}
}
}
}


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The loop for the labels can be done via `\foreach \Label [count=\X] in {a,...,k}
{\draw (X)  ++(-0.2+\X*0.4,0.2) node[anchor=south east] {$\Label$};}`. And your picture is simply too big, you can use `\usepackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,margin=0pt]{geometry}` and remove all the `\addtolength`s but it won't fit. You may either scale it down or add less of these structures per page. BTW, if you want to speed things up, you could use a pattern, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513715/194703.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here's a fix following the suggestions in Schrödinger's cat's comment :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,margin=0pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (-1,0) coordinate (Z);
\path (Z)++(0.2,0) coordinate (Y);
\foreach \bx in {0,5.5,11}
{
\foreach \by in {0,-6,-12,-18,-24}
{
\path (Y) ++(\bx,\by)  coordinate (X);
\foreach \Label [count=\X] in {a,...,k} {\draw (X) ++(-0.2+\X*0.4,0.2) node[anchor=south east] {$\Label$};}
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,11}
{
\draw (X)++(\x*0.2,-\x*0.4) ++(-0.2,0.4) node[anchor=east] {$\x$};
\foreach \y in {0,0.2,...,2}
{
\draw (X) ++(-0.4,0) ++(\x*0.4,0) ++(\y,-\y*2)  -- ++(0,0.2) -- ++(0.2,0.2) -- ++(0.2,-0.2)  -- ++(0,-0.2) -- ++(-0.2,-0.2) --cycle;
}}}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```