# How to create a Sierpinski triangle in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I have been trying to recreate the following image in LaTeX

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Ht9Gaow.jpg]

and for me personally it has to be done with pdflatex. Although answers using `pst-fractals`
From Jake I got a good start which led to the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\level{5}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[l-system={step=5pt, order=\level, angle=120},rotate=180]
    \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Sierpinski triangle}{
    \symbol{X}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
    \symbol{Y}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
    \rule{X -> X-Y+X+Y-X}
    \rule{Y -> YY}
    }
    \draw [black] (3,2) l-system
    [l-system={Sierpinski triangle, axiom=X, anchor=north east},fill=white];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There are however two problems with the code.

- I layer a black triangle behind the lindenmayersystem?
- How do I keep the size of the triangle consistent with different number of recursion levels.

Comment: Is there any formula for this? For instance we give which level we want and it produce the dimensions of the nodes?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The width of the background triangles is 2^order*stepsize, so you can calculate the step size as a function of the desired overall width:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}

\begin{document}%
\def\trianglewidth{2cm}%
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Sierpinski triangle}{
    \symbol{X}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
    \symbol{Y}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
    \rule{X -> X-Y+X+Y-X}
    \rule{Y -> YY}
}%
\foreach \level in {0,...,3}{%
\tikzset{
    l-system={step=\trianglewidth/(2^\level), order=\level, angle=-120}
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill [black] (0,0) -- ++(0:\trianglewidth) -- ++(120:\trianglewidth) -- cycle;
    \draw [draw=none] (0,0) l-system
    [l-system={Sierpinski triangle, axiom=X},fill=white];
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good answer! I will accept it tommorow =) Do you know any way to get rid of the parenthesis around the numbers here? 

http://pastebin.com/RBziPbWY

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: You can use `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}`

Answer (score 40):

An alternative way using decorations. It's a bit dependent on how the initial triangle is drawn (i.e., the direction of the path), and the nesting of decorations has to be done manually.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

% Not sure this follows any proper defition of 
% Sirpinksi triangle. It just works.
\pgfdeclaredecoration{quasi-sirpinski}{do}{%
    \state{do}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength, next state=do]{%
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{-60}{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/2}}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/2}{0pt}}%
        \pgfpathclose%
    }
}

\begin{document}

\tikz
    \fill (0,0) -- ++(60:3) -- ++(-60:3) -- cycle;

\tikz[decoration=quasi-sirpinski]
    \fill decorate { (0,0) -- ++(60:3) -- ++(-60:3) -- cycle };

\tikz[decoration=quasi-sirpinski]
    \fill decorate { decorate { 
        (0,0) -- ++(60:3) -- ++(-60:3) -- cycle } };

\tikz[decoration=quasi-sirpinski]
    \fill decorate { decorate { decorate { 
        (0,0) -- ++(60:3) -- ++(-60:3) -- cycle } } };

\tikz[decoration=quasi-sirpinski]
    \fill decorate { decorate { decorate {  decorate {
        (0,0) -- ++(60:3) -- ++(-60:3) -- cycle } } } };

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This is awesome. I didn't know that you could nest decorations!

Answer (score 34):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-fractal}
\begin{document}

\multido{\iA=1+1}{5}{%
 \begin{pspicture}(3,2.8)
 \psSier[linecolor=blue!70,fillcolor=red!40](0,0){3cm}{\iA}
 \end{pspicture}}

 \multido{\iA=1+1}{5}{%
   \begin{pspicture}(3,2.7)\psSier(0,0){3cm}{\iA} \end{pspicture}} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the color hurts ... ;-)

Comment: And pstricks rocks ;).

Answer (score 23):

Just for the looping fun of it; every section is one level... you can even automate the levels etc. but it's a little `xii.tex` way of doing it since it then becomes a lindenmayer system :)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
main tri/.style={isosceles triangle,fill,isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
                 rotate=90,inner sep=0,outer sep=0},
filler tri/.style={isosceles triangle,fill=white,rotate=-90,isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
                 inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]
\node[minimum height=2cm,main tri] (a) {};
%==================
\node[minimum height=1cm,filler tri] (b) at (a.center){};
%==================
\node[minimum height=0.5cm,filler tri,anchor=right corner] (c1) at (b.left side){};
\node[minimum height=0.5cm,filler tri,anchor=left corner] (c2) at (b.right side){};
\node[minimum height=0.5cm,filler tri,anchor=apex] (c3) at (b.west){};
% ===================
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
\node[minimum height=0.25cm,filler tri,anchor=right corner] (d1\x) at (c\x.left side){};
\node[minimum height=0.25cm,filler tri,anchor=left corner] (d2\x) at (c\x.right side){};
\node[minimum height=0.25cm,filler tri,anchor=apex] (d3\x) at (c\x.west){};
}
% ===================
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{
    \foreach \y in {1,2,3}{
    \node[minimum height=0.125cm,filler tri,anchor=right corner] (e1\x\y) at (d\x\y.left side){};
    \node[minimum height=0.125cm,filler tri,anchor=left corner] (e2\x\y) at (d\x\y.right side){};
    \node[minimum height=0.125cm,filler tri,anchor=apex] (e3\x\y) at (d\x\y.west){};
    }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I've just stumbled upon this problem, because it was linked to another I don't remember. Despite coming years too late, I couldn't resist to produce something with MetaPost. No particular package is loaded, it is just plain MetaPost code embedded into a LuaLaTeX program.

The main macro is simply called `Sierpinsky`. It takes the triangle's summits and the wished number of recursions as arguments, fills the triangle and proceeds with the required recursion.

**Edit** the algorithm has been improved. Now `Sierpinski` does not fill anything but only unfills the central subtriangle and calls itself on the other subtriangles. This at the cost of the creation of another macro, `Sierpinski_triangle`, which fills the first triangle and then calls `Sierpinski` upon it.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, multi=mplibcode]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \everymplib{
    vardef Sierpinski(expr A, B, C, n) = % The recursive macro, à la MetaPost
      if n>0: 
        save midAC, midBC, midAB; pair midAC, midBC, midAB;
        midAC = .5[A, C]; midBC = .5[B, C]; midAB = .5[A, B]; % The midpoints
        unfill midAC -- midBC -- midAB -- cycle;
        Sierpinski(A, midAB, midAC, n-1); 
        Sierpinski(midAC, midBC, C, n-1); 
        Sierpinski(midAB, B, midBC, n-1);
      fi
    enddef;
    def Sierpinski_triangle(expr A, B, C, n) =
      fill A--B--C--cycle; Sierpinski(A, B, C, n);
    enddef;
    beginfig(1);}
  \everyendmplib{endfig;}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    u = 3cm; % Size of the main triangle
    pair v; v = 1.1u*right; % translation vector
    for i = 0 upto 4:
      draw image(Sierpinski_triangle(origin, (u,0), u*dir 60, i)) shifted (i*v);
    endfor
  \end{mplibcode}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    u = 14cm;
    Sierpinski_triangle(origin, (u,0), u*dir 60, 8); % Eight levels of recursion
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With groups and counters.

### The output

with `\def\topDepth{8}`

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\count5=0 % current iteration depth
\count6=1 % previous size
\count7=0 % current x
\count8=0 % current y

\def\tri
{
  \ifnum\count5=\topDepth
    \draw 
      (\the\numexpr\count7+2\relax,\the\count8) -| 
      (\the\count7,\the\numexpr\count8+2\relax) -- 
      cycle;
  \else
    \begingroup
      \advance\count5 by 1
      \multiply\count6 by 2
      %
        \tri
      %
      \begingroup
        \advance\count7 by\count6
        \tri
      \endgroup
      %
      \begingroup
        \advance\count8 by\count6
        \tri
      \endgroup
    \endgroup
  \fi
}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\mySqrt}{sqrt(.75)}

\begin{document}

\def\topDepth{5}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=15*.5^\topDepth,cm={1,0,.5,\mySqrt,(0,0)}]
  \tri
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```