# How do I make Hanoi graphs using TikZ?

Tags: tkz-graph

I have a feeling that it is possible to do using tkz-graph, but I don't know how it works. I tried searching for high-resolution images in Google, and no such image showed up.

I need to make the graph with varying *n* so that the states of the Tower of Hanoi will be evident. A sample of the graph is from [WolframAlpha](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HanoiGraph.html).

Can you help me do it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are very similar to Sierpinski triangles (just without the fills). I'd start with one of the solutions at [How to create a Sierpinski triangle in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119602/how-to-create-a-sierpinski-triangle-in-latex) and make the minor adjustments necessary to get your desired result.