# TikZ: Intersection for Fraction Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, fractions

I am trying to create fraction diagrams for children using TikZ.

Is there an elegant way to fix the top of this diagram of 1/2 in a way that will scale when I want to show, say 29/6 with triangles... and eventually other shapes? It seems that intersections of paths that meet at non-90 degree angles don't quite intersect the way I want them to...

[image: Messed up picture]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\(\frac{1}{2}\)

\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=gray, draw=black, thick] (0,0)--(1,0)--(1,2)--cycle;
\draw[thick] (1,0)--(2,0)--(1,2)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: P.S. I am aware that in 15.3.1 of the TikZ/PGF Manual there the "miter" option, but this only seems to work *within* a single draw command. Is there a way to make it work *across* draw commands?

Comment: I don't think so. A new `\draw` starts a new path.

Comment: You could clip all subsequent drawing commands against the triangle (ie filldraw the triangle, then reuse the path with \clip and draw all the rest)

Comment: Sorry but I really do not think that it is polite to wait until you get a fantastic answer for any triangular case, and then update your question to require answers which can be used for `other shapes as well`. That changes the question very significantly and renders an extremely complete and sophisticated answer a merely partial one addressing only a special case. Do you really think that is fair? I would recommend undoing the edit, seriously considering accepting [the clearly best answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258542/) and asking a new question if needed specifying *which* shapes.

Comment: Actually, the question that was asked was how to make paths from different

Comment: [cont'd] `\draw` commands join more nicely for my fraction diagrams. I happened to use triangles as the *one example shape* because examples on this forum, I thought, are supposed to be minimal. I edited the original post because the pictures caused this thread to come across as way too triangle-focused, as opposed to path-joining-for-all-types-of-fraction-diagrams focused. Sorry for misleading anyone here; I greatly appreciate your responses! Next time I'll make sure my examples are broader more diverse.

Comment: Should I start a new thread about joining the paths from separate `\draw` commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but looking at the linked image, it seems to be so: I borrowed some code from [`Ignasi's answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229054/3954) to [How to draw triangular grid in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1943/3954). Since the triangular grid is built with `\node`s, you can easily use their anchors to do the filling, which I placed in the `background` layer:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

\newcommand\grid[1]{
\foreach \i [count=\row from 0, remember=\row as \lastrow (initially 0)] in {0,...,#1}
  {
  \foreach \j [count=\column from 0, remember=\column as \lastcolumn (initially 0)] in {0,...,\i}
    {
    \ifnum\row=0
      \node[tri](0-0) {};
    \else
      \ifnum\column=0
        \node[tri, anchor=north](\row-0) at (\lastrow-0.corner 2) {};
      \else
         \node[tri, anchor=north](\row-\column) at (\lastrow-\lastcolumn.corner 3) {};
      \fi
    \fi
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
tri/.style={
  draw,
  regular polygon,
  regular polygon sides=3, 
  minimum size=2cm, 
  inner sep=0pt,
  outer sep=0pt,
  line width=1pt
  }
]
\grid{3}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \filldraw[cyan!30] 
    (0-0.corner 1) -- 
    (3-3.corner 3) -- 
    (3-0.corner 2) -- 
    cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}

\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\grid{3}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \filldraw[cyan!30] 
    (3-0.corner 1) -- 
    (3-3.corner 1) -- 
    (3-3.corner 3) -- 
    (3-0.corner 2) -- 
    cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-8cm]
\grid{3}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \filldraw[cyan!30] 
    (2-0.corner 1) -- 
    (2-2.corner 1) -- 
    (3-1.corner 3) -- 
    cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,yshift=-8cm]
\grid{3}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \filldraw[cyan!30] 
    (0-0.corner 1) -- 
    (3-1.corner 3) -- 
    (3-0.corner 2) -- 
    cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}
\draw[line width=1pt]
  (0-0.corner 1) -- (3-1.corner 3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Most impressive. I knew I'd seen something like this somewhere before. Too bad the OP has just updated the question to include other shapes as well ;).

Comment: Please read my comment above about editing the OP. Also, I'll still be using this for sure!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to fill first and then draw a single path:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [fill=gray] (0,0)--(1,0)--(1,2)--cycle;
  \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (1,2) edge (1,0) -- (2,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: fill then draw]

## What's an `edge`?

An `edge` is an independent bit of path which can go off in a different direction and may be drawn (or not) with completely different options from the main path. It does not disrupt the main path. In this case, the `edge` draws the perpendicular down, but the main path carries on from the vertex as if no `edge` had been specified. `edge`s are useful for complex paths, especially. They are constructed after the main path.

To see what is going on, change the path specification as follows:

```
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (1,2) edge [red] (1,0) -- (2,0) -- cycle;
```

By default, the `edge` inherits options from the main path so this one is `thick` but, unlike the main path, it is `red`. In the above image, of course, no distinct options were specified so the `edge` was also the default colour and blended with the main path.

[image: red edge]

Comment: That works for 1/2. But if I wanted to do 29/6, would I then have to write a lot more `\fill` and `\draw` commands, right? It seemed more efficient when I could use the `\filldraw` command and take care of both in a single line. It also seems that drawing the path of more complex fractions with one draw command might be really hard... If that's what I have to do, though, then I'll just suck it up and do it.

Comment: Also, what does the "edge" part do?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything To be honest, I don't know what you are trying to draw. That is, I don't know just how this scales up. So I don't know what's possible. Is `\fill` + `\draw` worse than `\filldraw` + \draw`? Can you post or link to am image of the 29/6 version or something in between which would give an idea of the pattern? There may be a better way, though - I'm no TikZ guru.

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything See edit re. `edge`s.

Comment: [Eventually, I'd like to draw something like this](http://i.imgur.com/l0hGvcU.jpg), but probably even more complicated. Notice the large number of intersections and separately shaded areas. It would be great to take care of paths and fills in the same line.