# Triangle Fraction Diagrams: Segments Instead of Gaps

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles, fractions

I would like to modify [Mark Wibrow's triangular fraction diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258742/tikz-fill-for-fraction-diagram/258777#258777) so that black segments are drawn, rather than leaving a blank white space between the triangles. As I do not understand how the code works, I thought I would reach out to the community for help:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\newcount\tikzfractiondenominator
\newcount\tikzfractionnumerator
\def\tikzfractionempty{}
\let\tikzfractionstyle=\tikzfractionempty
\newif\iftikzfractionfill
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  fraction/.style={%
    code={%
      \tikzset{pics/fraction/.cd, #1}%
      \pgfmathparse{int(ceil(\tikzfractionnumerator/\tikzfractiondenominator))}%
      \let\tikzfractionshapetotal=\pgfmathresult
      \ifx\tikzfractionstyle\tikzfractionempty
      \else%
        \pgfmathloop
          \ifnum\tikzfractionnumerator<1
        \else
          \pgfmathsetmacro\tikzfractionproper{int(\tikzfractionnumerator?\tikzfractionnumerator:\tikzfractiondenominator)}%
          \foreach \tikzfractionsegmentnumber in {1,...,\tikzfractiondenominator}{%
            \ifnum\tikzfractionsegmentnumber>\tikzfractionproper\relax%
              \tikzfractionfillfalse%
            \else%
              \tikzfractionfilltrue%
            \fi%
            \let\tikzfractionshapenumber=\pgfmathcounter%
            \begin{scope}
              \tikzset{pics/fraction/\tikzfractionstyle/shape position/.try}%
              \tikzset{pics/fraction/\tikzfractionstyle/segment position/.try}%
              \tikzset{pics/fraction/\tikzfractionstyle/segment draw/.try}%
            \end{scope}
          }% 
          \advance\tikzfractionnumerator by-\tikzfractiondenominator%
        \repeatpgfmathloop%
      \fi%
    }
  },
  fraction/.cd,
    style/.store in=\tikzfractionstyle,
    numerator/.code=\pgfmathsetcount\tikzfractionnumerator{#1},
    denominator/.code=\pgfmathsetcount\tikzfractiondenominator{#1},
    fraction/.style args={#1/#2}{%
      /tikz/pics/fraction/.cd,
        numerator={#1}, denominator={#2}
    }
}
\tikzset{%
  /tikz/pics/fraction/triangles/.cd,
    shape position/.code={
      \pgfmathsetmacro\y{sqrt(\tikzfractiondenominator)}
      \tikzset{
        shift=(0:{(\tikzfractionshapenumber-1)*\y}),
        shift={(0,\y/4)},
      }
    },
    segment position/.code={
      \let\i=\tikzfractionsegmentnumber
      \pgfmathsetmacro\z{int(sqrt(\i-1))}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\q{\i-(\z)^2}
      \tikzset{
        shift={({sin(60) * (\q-\z) / 2}, {-\z*0.75 -mod(\q,2)*cos(60)/2})},
        rotate={mod(\q-1,2)*180}
      }
    },
    segment draw/.code={
      \iftikzfractionfill
        \tikzset{triangle fill/.style={blue!50!cyan!50}}
      \else
        \tikzset{triangle fill/.style={gray!20}}
      \fi
      \fill [triangle fill] (90:0.45) -- (210:0.45) -- (330:0.45) -- cycle;
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \numerator/\denominator [count=\y]  in {1/1, 2/4, 13/9}{
\tikzset{shift=(270:\y*2)}
\pic {fraction={style=triangles, fraction={\numerator/\denominator}}};
\node at (-1,0)  {$\frac{\numerator}{\denominator}$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258542/48036) that draws nice-looking triangle fraction diagrams similar to what I am looking for, but I am hoping for a solution that allows me to continue using Mark Wibrow's simple `\begin{tikzpicture}\pic{fraction={style=triangles, fraction={2/4}}};\end{tikzpicture}` macro. Thank you in advance!

Comment: For my humble opinion it is a very good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minimal surgery, i.e. replacing

```
segment draw/.code={
  \iftikzfractionfill
    \tikzset{triangle fill/.style={blue!50!cyan!50}}
  \else
    \tikzset{triangle fill/.style={gray!20}}
  \fi
  \fill [triangle fill] (90:0.45) -- (210:0.45) -- (330:0.45) -- cycle;
}
```

by

```
segment draw/.code={
  \iftikzfractionfill
    \tikzset{triangle fill/.style={fill=blue!50!cyan!50}}
  \else
    \tikzset{triangle fill/.style={fill=gray!20}}
  \fi
  \draw [triangle fill] (90:0.500) -- (210:0.500) -- (330:0.500) -- cycle;
}
```

yields

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\newcount\tikzfractiondenominator
\newcount\tikzfractionnumerator
\def\tikzfractionempty{}
\let\tikzfractionstyle=\tikzfractionempty
\newif\iftikzfractionfill
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  fraction/.style={%
    code={%
      \tikzset{pics/fraction/.cd, #1}%
      \pgfmathparse{int(ceil(\tikzfractionnumerator/\tikzfractiondenominator))}%
      \let\tikzfractionshapetotal=\pgfmathresult
      \ifx\tikzfractionstyle\tikzfractionempty
      \else%
        \pgfmathloop
          \ifnum\tikzfractionnumerator<1
        \else
          \pgfmathsetmacro\tikzfractionproper{int(\tikzfractionnumerator?\tikzfractionnumerator:\tikzfractiondenominator)}%
          \foreach \tikzfractionsegmentnumber in {1,...,\tikzfractiondenominator}{%
            \ifnum\tikzfractionsegmentnumber>\tikzfractionproper\relax%
              \tikzfractionfillfalse%
            \else%
              \tikzfractionfilltrue%
            \fi%
            \let\tikzfractionshapenumber=\pgfmathcounter%
            \begin{scope}
              \tikzset{pics/fraction/\tikzfractionstyle/shape position/.try}%
              \tikzset{pics/fraction/\tikzfractionstyle/segment position/.try}%
              \tikzset{pics/fraction/\tikzfractionstyle/segment draw/.try}%
            \end{scope}
          }% 
          \advance\tikzfractionnumerator by-\tikzfractiondenominator%
        \repeatpgfmathloop%
      \fi%
    }
  },
  fraction/.cd,
    style/.store in=\tikzfractionstyle,
    numerator/.code=\pgfmathsetcount\tikzfractionnumerator{#1},
    denominator/.code=\pgfmathsetcount\tikzfractiondenominator{#1},
    fraction/.style args={#1/#2}{%
      /tikz/pics/fraction/.cd,
        numerator={#1}, denominator={#2}
    }
}
\tikzset{%
  /tikz/pics/fraction/triangles/.cd,
    shape position/.code={
      \pgfmathsetmacro\y{sqrt(\tikzfractiondenominator)}
      \tikzset{
        shift=(0:{(\tikzfractionshapenumber-1)*\y}),
        shift={(0,\y/4)},
      }
    },
    segment position/.code={
      \let\i=\tikzfractionsegmentnumber
      \pgfmathsetmacro\z{int(sqrt(\i-1))}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\q{\i-(\z)^2}
      \tikzset{
        shift={({sin(60) * (\q-\z) / 2}, {-\z*0.75 -mod(\q,2)*cos(60)/2})},
        rotate={mod(\q-1,2)*180}
      }
    },
    segment draw/.code={
      \iftikzfractionfill
        \tikzset{triangle fill/.style={fill=blue!50!cyan!50}}
      \else
        \tikzset{triangle fill/.style={fill=gray!20}}
      \fi
      \draw [triangle fill] (90:0.500) -- (210:0.500) -- (330:0.500) -- cycle;
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \numerator/\denominator [count=\y]  in {1/1, 2/4, 13/9}{
\tikzset{shift=(270:\y*2)}
\pic {fraction={style=triangles, fraction={\numerator/\denominator}}};
\node at (-1,0)  {$\frac{\numerator}{\denominator}$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!