# Triangular numbers (again) in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, grids

I am trying to recreate the following diagram for triangular numbers (smaller triangles within one larger triangle) using TikZ.

[image]

The colour is not important but white and grey is probably preferred.

I have tried to modify the code used [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/how-to-draw-triangular-grid-in-tikz) which produces a triangular grid but without success (I do not know how to produce more than one grid in a single figure and could not shade the triangles in the alternating pattern shown) and is the reason why I have not included any MWE.

Ideally the code would be flexible enough to choose the number of larger triangles required (6 are shown in the above figure).

Comment: Show what you have done already.

Comment: Like I said, using the code in the link I can produce a single triangular grid only with no shading. I need multiple triangular grids on the same diagram that grow in size and are shaded along each column. This is what I do not know how to do.

Comment: So you refuse to make a minimal example?  Here, have my downvote. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @Henri - that is fine. It still does not solve my problem. Like I have said, I have tried to modify code I thought would be useful to solve my problem but I simply do not know how to make it work. What I can produce is a single triangular grid with 1, 2, 3, ... columns but cannot fit more than one of these grids onto a single diagram and have no ideal how to shade them as I require.

Comment: Which code exactly? There are eight answers to that question.

Comment: You still don't seem to understand.  Please carefully read the information on this page: [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @Henri - I understand MWEs are usually required and is the reason why I explicitly mentioned in my original posting that I simply didn't have one since I was unable to not make any real progress on the problem.

Comment: @ Torbjørn - Sorry, I was working on the code provided in the accepted solution.

Comment: Then you could have turned that into a complete document (documentclass, `tikz` package and `document` environment is missing) and added it to your question.

Comment: @HenriMenke The MWE is in the linked question.  What are you trying to get out of this forcing? Are you planning to answer the question?

Comment: @percusse As I already stated: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @HenriMenke After downvoting please stop alienating users then. There is nothing wrong with this question and you show **no attempt** of engaging to answer it so leave it to people who are interested.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\triangles[2]{\def\w{#1}\foreach\n in{1,...,#2}{\path
    ([xshift=\w]current bounding box.south east)coordinate(O);
    \foreach\s[count=\c]in{\n,...,1}{\foreach\m in{1,...,\s}{
        \fill[green!50!black](O)++(60:{(\c-1)*\w})++(0:{(\m-1)*\w})--
        ++(60:\w)--++(-60:\w)--cycle;}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\triangles{3mm}{8}\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

A small modification of [Ignasi's answer on the question you refer to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229054/586):

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{
  tri/.style={
    draw=none,
    fill=black!50,
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=3, 
    minimum size=2cm,
    inner sep=0pt,
    outer sep=0pt
 }
}

\newcommand{\grid}[1]{
\foreach \i [count=\row from 0, remember=\row as \lastrow (initially 0)] in {0,...,#1}{
    \foreach \j [count=\column from 0, remember=\column as \lastcolumn (initially 0)] in {0,...,\i}{
        \ifnum\row=0
            \node[tri](0-0){};
        \else
            \ifnum\column=0
                \node[tri, anchor=corner 2](\row-0) at (\lastrow-0.corner 3) {};
            \else
                \node[tri, anchor=corner 2](\row-\column) at (\lastrow-\lastcolumn.corner 1) {};
            \fi
        \fi}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
{
\begin{scope}[xshift=2*\x cm + \x*\x cm]
 \grid{\x}
\end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's nice to know that an answer is good enough to be recycled.

Comment: `\foreach` options will never stop surprising me...

Answer (score 4):

Almost as compact in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html)...

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
picture trig; 
trig = image(fill origin -- right -- right rotated 60 -- cycle withcolor 1/2 white);
for k=1 upto 7:
    for j=1 upto k:
        for i=1 upto j:
            draw trig 
                 shifted (1/2(k+1)*k + 1/2(k-j) + i, sqrt(3/4)*(k-j))
                 scaled 5mm;
        endfor
    endfor
endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

The trick here is that the `scaled 5mm` scales both the triangle picture and the amount it's shifted.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one path approach which allows one to use the whole construct for shadings or clipping.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  triangles/.style 2 args={
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathtruncatemacro \n         {#2}%
                \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\size      {(#1)*\n}%
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro \iterations{\n/2},
    line join=round, insert path={
      (210:\size) coordinate(x) (-30:\size) coordinate(y) (90:\size)coordinate (z)
      foreach[evaluate={\f=\i/\n;}]\i in {0, ..., \iterations}{
          ($(x)!\f!(y)$) -- ($(x)!\f!(z)$) -- ($(y)!\f!(z)$)
        \unless\ifnum\pgfinteval{2*\i}=\n\relax
        --($(y)!\f!(x)$) -- ($(z)!\f!(x)$) -- ($(z)!\f!(y)$)
        \fi -- cycle}}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz\path[ball color=blue, triangles={5mm}{6}];
\tikz\matrix[
  row sep=5mm, column sep=5mm, execute at empty cell={
    \draw[fill=green!50!black, triangles=
      {5mm}{\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+5*\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-5}];}]{
   & & & & \\ & & & & \\ & & & & \\};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With Asymptote: for a specific triangle

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(6cm);
int n=8;
path p=(0,0)--(1,0)--dir(60)--cycle;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
for (int j=0; j<n-i; ++j)
fill(shift(i*dir(60)+(j,0))*p,purple);
```

and for a series of triangle: we can make a function returning a picture with a parameter for its size and add to the current picture by `add(alttriangle());` (default `n=8`), or `add(alttriangle(5));`, or `add(alttriangle(n=5));`

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(12cm);
picture alttriangle(int n=8){
picture temp;
path p=(0,0)--(1,0)--dir(60)--cycle;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
for (int j=0; j<n-i; ++j)
fill(temp,shift(i*dir(60)+(j,0))*p,purple);
return temp;
}

int n=7;
for (int i=1; i<n; ++i) 
add(shift(i*(i+1)/2,0)*alttriangle(i));

//shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```