# tikz drawing rectangle discretized with triangle lattices and its centroids

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to draw the following figure using tikz [image]

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/how-to-draw-triangular-grid-in-tikz) post is similar but the for loops are complicated for me to understand.

The rectangle domain is 2.0 x 1.0 (width x height) and there are 20 subdivisions along horizontal direction and 10 subdivisions along vertical directions.

The blue dots are centroids of the triangle

Any help/clue will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One needs to find an algorithm to draw it. The following is one of such algorithms.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw[gray] (0,0) grid (20,10);
\foreach \i in {0,...,9} {
    % Draw the grid
    \draw[gray] (0,\i) -- (10-\i,10);
    \draw[gray] (10+\i,0) -- (20,10-\i);
    \ifnum\i=0\relax\else
        \draw[gray] (\i,0) -- (10+\i,10);\fi
    % Draw the dots
    \foreach \j in {0,...,19} {
        % The center of each square is \j+.5 and \i+.5
        \coordinate (center) at (\j+.5,\i+.5);
        \fill[blue] ([shift={(-1/6,1/6)}]center) circle (3pt);
        \fill[blue] ([shift={(1/6,-1/6)}]center) circle (3pt);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

An alternative construction with a `matrix` and `nodes in empty cells`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    mymatrix/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={draw=gray,
            minimum size=1cm,
            outer sep=0pt,
            inner sep=0pt,
            anchor=center,
            path picture={%
                \draw (path picture bounding box.north east)--(path picture bounding box.south west);
                \fill[blue] ([shift={(-1/6,1/6)}]path picture bounding box.center) circle(3pt);
                \fill[blue] ([shift={(1/6,-1/6)}]path picture bounding box.center) circle(3pt);
            }
        }
    }
]
\matrix[mymatrix]{%
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yet another alternative: `pic`s. And store the variables in pgf keys. Like Joule V's nice solution, this grid can be transformed (e.g. rotated) without resorting to `transform canvas`, which tends to mess up things.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/cell/.style={code={\draw (-#1,-#1) rectangle (#1,#1)
(-#1,-#1) -- (#1,#1);
\fill[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cell/color}]
(135:{#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cell/circle pos}}) 
circle[radius=#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cell/radius}] 
(-45:{#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cell/circle pos}})
circle[radius=#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cell/radius}];}},
cell/.cd,color/.initial=blue,radius/.initial=1/6,circle pos/.initial={sqrt(0.5)}]
\path foreach \X in {1,...,20}
{foreach \Y in {1,...,10} {(\X,\Y) pic[cell/radius=1/5,cell/circle pos=1/2]{cell=0.5}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]